# how to select the right features for my regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to increase accuracy of my model for blog feedback dataset problem
 in UCI machine learning repository. I need help with feature selection.

I'm new to machine learning. I have selected features by using p value and adjusted r squared method but still accuracy of my model is very low . What should i do now?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Consider asking in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In my understanding of linear regression, *reducing* the number of features cannot *increase* R-squared. It is reasonable to remove features that do not contribute to the model in this regard as they are considered unnecessary .

Comment: have you tried to explore your data to see whether it's linearly separable before using linear regression. because if it's not you may radically change the way of your way to do feature selection like using feature crossing.